# issues loading an IPad App I made on testers IPad. currently not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I made a simple chat app, not much more than telnet, and i've just started learning IOS and Objective C. I've programmed in Java, C and C++ in the past. One of the last steps i want to accomplish before i pause a bit and read up more on what i'm doing, is loading the app on my IPad and my Testers. I have got it working on my IPad but not my tester and he is remote.

I compiled the App in Xtools, did Archive, and exported the .ipa file by going into windows/ Organizer in the xtools menu, and selecting the archive menu to get at the project i archived then doing share and opening it in file so i could get at the IPA file to distribute.  I added my device and my testers device in the provisioning profile earlier.

When i installed it a few days ago on my ipad originally i used xcode. I had got issued a certificate in the provisioning portal or something and i think i dragged it on top of some keybind or keychain thing.  But i don't recall those steps exactly anymore i just know it works in my ipad.

For the tester i had an ad hoc provisioning profile made which i mailed to the tester along with the .ipa file.  He was able to load app with itunes i think but it said app not installed. After that we tried testflight service. he was able to get to the point that it said install this app but it wouldn't install.  I went to the testflight download link and i was able to install from there after first deleting my app from my ipad. In the ipad settings i see my ad hoc provision certificate thing.

I'm not sure if i'm missing a step that is different for installing on a testers ipad, ( i do have his device right because test flight wouldn't let you try to install from it's links if you were not a listed device).

Is there some special build process in xcode i need to do here? Do i need to drag the ad hoc over the keybind or keychain app?  He is using windows and i use a mac.  He says he thinks he is a member of the developer network but we weren't sure that was required.  He does have access to a mac.  I want to eventually expand to several testers but this particular tester i've worked closely with on other software ( non ios) in past.  He is on ipad 1 and i am on ipad 2 though i did change the minimum IOS to run it to just 5.0 which was the minimum i think i could use and still keep automatic reference counting.

thanks in advance for any help
Mike

Comment: could it have something to do with i added my testers device after i got my first provisioning certificate like a day later when i was already running it on my ipad?

Comment: No - the certificate doesn't change. Am I right in thinking that you are using a *Provisioning* Profile and he is using an *Ad-Hoc Distribution* Profile?

Comment: i got it working on my ipad before i created the ad hoc. i created the ad hoc because i had found in searching that was how you distribute to testers. I did install from the install site ( test flight) with the add hoc, but that may be not the whole case that i'm using the add hoc if i already had a provisioning profile i used with xtools. but yea i got it working on my ipad before i created the ad hoc

Comment: If he's installing with an Ad-Hoc profile, you need to set the build settings to use your *Distribution* certificate instead of your *Developer* certificate. I normally duplicate the Release build configuration, name it "Ad-Hoc" and set it to use the Distribution certificate. Then for the Archive scheme settings I tell it to use the Ad-Hoc configuration.

Comment: I have a certificate i named IOS team provisioning profile, and in the provisioning section i see my IOS team profile ( managed by xcode), on the development tab, if i click the distribution tab i see add hoc for testers. All i did with add hoc for the testers was create it and send it off.  Do i need to perform a build step to link it into my application? Do i need to do some type of keychain thing with it?

Comment: Yes - you need to follow the steps in the distribution section to create your distribution certificate.

Comment: i can in xcode change it from using the code signing identify of my ios team provisioning certificate and use identities without provisioning profiles: distribution: My Name. If i change it there how do i know xcode will build with it and i'm not just changing a profile? if its the current build settings when i click on my app in  xcode does that mean it's using it? i did change build options debug to no and release to yes yesterday.

Comment: It will use it - try! Just remember when you install it on your device you will need to put it back to the provisioning certificate, or, alternatively, you could add yourself to the Ad-Hoc profile (which I recommend) - neither will require you to re-download the certificate.

Comment: Your tester's UDID is in your adhoc profile? Check the file `embedded.mobileprovision` in your ipa.

Comment: I got it working for my tester now.  I created the ad hoc but i didn't import it until last night into xcode and then change my signing identity. I went into the organizer and from there imported the add hoc and change the build setting and pushed to him and it worked.  But now i have a second tester who sent me his machine id  this morning.  If i add his id tonight in my provisioning portal, will it update the ad hoc automatically? do i need to make a new ad hoc now? If i make a new one with everyone will the old one stop working for my current tester till i push everyone the new? thnks Mike

Comment: It will keep working for your current tester but will require you to rebuild with the new profile for the new tester to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my question to explain as an answer how i got this to work.

I created the ad hoc but i didn't import it until last night(June 26 2012) into xcode through the organizer and then change my code signing identity to distribution. I went into the organizer and from there imported the add hoc and change the build setting and pushed to him via testflight and he was able to install. I had simply sent the add hoc i had created along with the build which is not sufficient.